# I am writing a unit test for one of me mapping function using jest with typescript, but I am facing an error ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

This is the unit test I have wrote,

```
describe('Test getDataObject', () => {
    it('Generates data object', async () => {

        const Data = Mapping.getDataObject(
            connection, ILInput
        );

        expect(Data).toEqual(orderResult);
    });
});
```

here, `connection`, `ILInput` and `orderResult` are mock objects I have created.
and
`Mapping.getDataObject` is a function name

I have also tried,

```
describe('Test getAssignmentDataObject', () => {
    it('Generates assignment data object form the loads getting from loadboard ', async () => {

        async function getData() {
            try {
                const Data = await Mapping.getDataObject(connection, ILInput);

                return Data;
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        };

        expect(getData).toEqual(orderResult);

    });
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTNeE.png)

and this is the error I am facing:

```
node:internal/process/promises:246
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise 
which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')".] {      
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
```

**Please suggest me some ways to resolve this.**